# Reading text line by line with StreamReader and converting lines to std::string in C++

Tags: c++, winforms, c++-cli, streamreader, stdstring

I'm writing a programm in C++ using winforms, and I have troubles using fstream (as in console applications). I have two questions:1)Can I use fstream in winforms?
2) How to read a textfile line by line and convert that lines to std::string.
I have this code, but it doesn't work:

```
    std::string fileName = "data.txt";
  System::String^ FileName = gcnew System::String(fileName.data());
    System::IO::StreamReader^ sr;
    sr = gcnew System::IO::StreamReader(FileName);
    std::string current;
    System::String^ line;
    while ((line = sr->ReadLine()) != nullptr) {
       std::string current = msclr::interop::marshal_as<std::string>(line);
       //doing other stuff..
    }
```

When I try ifstream to read the file, it doesn't do anything. When I go with debugger step by step, there's always some problem - like "msvcp 140d.i386.pdb is not loaded" - when I load it, there's another one and on and on. But when I try to read it with StreamReader, I can't compile it, probably because I can't convert line = sr->ReadLine() to std::string

This code also doesn't work:

```
*std::string fileName = "data.txt";
System::String^ FileName = gcnew System::String(fileName.data());
        System::IO::StreamReader^ file = System::IO::File::OpenText(FileName);
        System::String^ line;
        line = file->ReadLine();
while (file->Peek()>=0) {
            line = file->ReadLine()->ToString();
//or line = file->ReadLine(); - doesn't work either
            std::string current = msclr::interop::marshal_as<std::string>(line);
//...
}*
```

Comment: `#include <fstream> //[...] std::ifstream f(fileName); if (f) { // read the content }` -- What is not working? Do you actually need to marshal `System::String` to `std::string`? Can't you use the former instead? Applies also to, e.g., `String^ fileName = L"data.txt";`, which you can directly pass to the StreamReader.

Comment: When I use fstream in console apps, it works fine. But here, when I run my program step by step, it eventually gives a mistake: msvcp 140d.i386.pdb is not loaded. 
I need to convert current to std::string to do other stuff in my program, System::String^ would make it many times harder.

Comment: That's just the debugging Symbols of a library; it's not an error, you're trying to step into the source code. Do you need to? In break mode, you should have the option to select a Symbol Server (e.g., Microsoft Symbol Server), check it and click the `Load` Button. Note that this, if you don't uncheck that option later (from Tools->Options->Debugging->Symbols) will instruct to download all .pdb files of all System libraries (kind of a behemoth)

Comment: You can press F10 instead of F11 to step over the current line, without going into the include files. E.g., if you write `std::ifstream f(fileName);
if (f) { std::string line; while (std::getline(f, line)) { Debug::WriteLine(gcnew String(line.data())); } }` to print to the Output pane the content of the lines of text, you can set a breakpoint on the first line of code, then press F10 on each line to see the result of each call.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! A managed to read the file and can continue on my app!